# Can't change Animation frame number in unity3D

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am trying to create an button animation in unity

When i create the clip,

frame number stays on 60 by default

then i change the frame number, but after moving the mouse pointer it go back to 60

i tried in again again by deleting the clip and recreating the clip

but no effect

still the same

for better understanding

**1. when i create the clip**

[image]

**2. changing the frame number 60 to 0**

[image]

**3. after moving mouse pointer it back again to 60**

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? That is the number of frames per second. You can't have 0 frames per second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to change total frame number.

[image]

Yes, It's in Unity 5.6 and upper versions, so that can be confusing.

If you look above to your sample 60 bar, you can see a place where 0 is typed:

[image]

That's your current frame
and you can make your desired animation changing the current time frame.

Comment: @SHAHMDIMRANHOSSAIN Okay I edited it. I hope this time its clear :)

Answer (score 1):

That number is the **Sampling Rate** of the animation, i.e. how many frames of that animation clip are "executed" in a second.

60 means the animation runs at 60fps, or 1 frame every 16.6ms, so the general formula is:

`Sample` = `Number of frames / second`

Hence, you can't set that value to 0, an animation that runs at 0 fps is a still frame.

To get a specific frame of the animation, you need to move the red vertical line or click on a specific time on the timeline bar.